# $F(x) = \frac{\alpha x^{\alpha - 1}}{\beta^\alpha}, 0 < x < \beta$, find mle of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Tags: statistics

$F(x) = \frac{\alpha x^{\alpha - 1}}{\beta^\alpha}, 0 < x < \beta$, find mle of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

i have calculated the log-likelihood $\log L(\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\alpha^n}{\beta^{n\alpha}}\prod x_i^{\alpha-1}$ and its derivative w.r.t $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as follows

$\frac{n}{\alpha} - n\log \beta + \sum \log x_i = 0$ and $-\frac{n\alpha}{\beta} = 0$.
i find i can't solve this equation. how to solve this problem?

Comment: Maxima can happen at the end points as well as where the derivative is $0$.  You might want to consider that $x \le \beta \iff \beta \ge x$ for all the observations or use indicator functions in your likelihood.

Comment: To fill in the gaps in @Henry's comment, maxima can occur at endpoints - you are in one such case. By inspection, you can observe that $\beta = \max_i x_i$. From there it should be easy to find what $\alpha$ should be.

Comment: @Gregory Thanks! I had understood his meaning.